# GWT module to export a table

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt

I am working on a GWT project. I have a MultiSelectionModel with data that I want to export to excel. I have looked at the following module, but eclipse tells me it is deprecated. Does anyone know if it will still work, and if it only works on table?

https://code.google.com/p/gwt-table-to-excel/

Comment: When it says deprecated, it means it still works but it's not a preferred way.

Comment: thx. Any idea of a better way?

Comment: first of all, it's the java compiler that complains about the method(s) you used, and not eclipse. Second, the jar file you have included in your class path is not deprecated, it's a (or a few) specific method or class within this gwt api that is deprecated. you need to look up this method on the api doc page and see what the replacement methods are.

Comment: I used the Apachae poi instead. Worked.